# Disable Telerik Chart Legend by default

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How can I make one of the legend of a `RadHtmlChart` chart display unchecked by default when loading the chart.

Current Chart: [current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7OR.png)

Desired Chart: [desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfCKW.png)

Current telerik asp:

```
<telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" Skin="Bootstrap" ID="RhcIndicadores" Transitions="true">
    <Legend>
        <Appearance Position="Bottom"></Appearance>
    </Legend>
    <PlotArea>
        <Series>
            <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="Cantidad" Name="Cantidad">
                <LabelsAppearance Position="InsideBase" DataFormatString="{0:0}">
                    <TextStyle Color="White" />
                </LabelsAppearance>
                <TooltipsAppearance>
                    <ClientTemplate>Cantidad: #=dataItem.Cantidad# requerimientos.</br>Participación: #= kendo.format(\'{0:N}\', dataItem.Participacion)#%.</br>Rango: #=dataItem.Rango#.</ClientTemplate>
                </TooltipsAppearance>
            </telerik:ColumnSeries>

            <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="Participacion" Name="Participación" AxisName="AdditionalAxis">
                <Appearance>
                    <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#ACB72F" />
                </Appearance>
                <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%">
                    <TextStyle Color="#ACB72F" />
                </LabelsAppearance>
                <TooltipsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%"></TooltipsAppearance>
            </telerik:LineSeries>

            <telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="ParetoAcumulado" Name="Pareto Acumulado" AxisName="AdditionalAxisPareto">
                <Appearance>
                    <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#5BC0DE" />
                </Appearance>
                <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%" Position="Above">
                    <TextStyle Color="#5BC0DE" Bold="true" />
                </LabelsAppearance>
                <TooltipsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%"></TooltipsAppearance>
            </telerik:LineSeries>
        </Series>
        <XAxis DataLabelsField="Rango">
            <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="45"></LabelsAppearance>
            <AxisCrossingPoints>
                <telerik:AxisCrossingPoint Value="0" />
                <telerik:AxisCrossingPoint Value="11" />
            </AxisCrossingPoints>
            <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
            <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
        </XAxis>
        <YAxis Color="#337AB7">
            <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
            <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
        </YAxis>
        <AdditionalYAxes>
            <telerik:AxisY Name="AdditionalAxis" Color="#ACB72F">
                <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%"></LabelsAppearance>
            </telerik:AxisY>

            <telerik:AxisY Name="AdditionalAxisPareto" Color="#5BC0DE">
                <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%"></LabelsAppearance>
            </telerik:AxisY>

        </AdditionalYAxes>
    </PlotArea>
</telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the answer, in the desired series it should be indicated `Visible="false"` and `VisibleInLegend="true"`:

```
<telerik:LineSeries DataFieldY="ParetoAcumulado" Name="Pareto Acumulado"
 Visible="false" VisibleInLegend="true" AxisName="AdditionalAxisPareto">
    <Appearance>
        <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#5BC0DE" />
    </Appearance>
    <LabelsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%" Position="Above">
        <TextStyle Color="#5BC0DE" Bold="true" />
    </LabelsAppearance>
    <TooltipsAppearance DataFormatString="{0:N}%"></TooltipsAppearance>
</telerik:LineSeries>
```